# JsRender: How to pass variables into a nested template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I want to use a nested template in different parts of my webpage. For the different parts I need to get a value from an array within the nested template. I cannot use a for loop because each part has different class and position on the website. Is it possible to pass a variable into the nested template? The following code simplifies what I am trying to achieve:

```
<script id="myBtnTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <button class="btn">        
        {{:myData.myArray[INDEX_VARIABLE].btnName}}
    </button>
</script>

//  Here I want to use INDEX_VARIABLE = 0
<div class="BigButton">
    {{if myData tmpl="myBtnTmpl"/}}
</div>

//  Here I want to use INDEX_VARIABLE = 1
<div class="MediumButton">
    {{if myData tmpl="myBtnTmpl"/}}
</div>

//  Here I want to use INDEX_VARIABLE = 2
<div class="SmallButton">
    {{if myData tmpl="myBtnTmpl"/}}
</div>
```

Another question: When using nested templates is it possible to include nested templates like this {{tmpl="myBtnTmpl"/}} without the if syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: For second question, {{for myData tmpl="#myBtnTmpl"/}} But totally don't understand your original question..

Comment: Anyway, according to the title, I think you can have a reference at https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/step-by-step/06_template-composition.html

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can set named template parameters on the tag where you are using `tmpl="myBtnTmpl"` (whether that be an `{{if}}` tag or a `{{for}}` tag):

```
<div class="BigButton">
    {{for myData ~arrIndex=0 tmpl="myBtnTmpl"/}}
</div>
```

Then you can access the template parameter in the same way you would access a registered helper - by appending '~' to the name.

```
<button class="btn">        
    {{:myData.myArray[~arrIndex].btnName}}
</button>
```

Incidentally, you can also pass variables and helper functions (in addition to the data) with the render method. I just added a new [sample demo](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/12_passing-in-context.html) showing that.

So what this means is that templates can be 'parameterized' similarly whether you are rendering them from code, or declaratively as in your nested templates above.

Comment: Hi Boris and thanks for your quick reply. I followed your example and I put ~arrIndex=0 on the tag. However the template does not seem to find the variable when I try to access it within the template. I am using the latest commit count 19. Did it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for still supporting jsRender, u should put a showCase on the official page

Comment: @boban984: You mean showing links to sites using JsRender or JsViews?

Comment: @BorisMoore Yes, i feel like jsRender is underappreciated.I've been using it since it was in alpha stage, before there was jsViews :)

At the time there was no Angular or Ember, Backbone and Knockout were just getting popular, but jsRender was way more perfomant for our needs so that's why we picked it.

I am still using it ... check [Solaborate](https://www.solaborate.com/)

Comment: @BobanStojanovski: Thanks - good to hear. Of course I know there are many folks out there doing very cool things and making cool sites with JsRender or JsViews - but it is difficult to find out who they are, or establish a list of such sites. Also many of them are powerful internal sites - not public facing ones. That's why so far I haven't yet tried to establish a 'gallery'... (If you have further thoughts about that, I'd be happy to exchange via email - borismoore@gmail.com)

Comment: You are right, only thing i can think of is to put some form or whatever on the site where people can send you the urls of their apps.