# Embedding a jsRender template without {{for}} or combining inline + block templates

Tags: jsrender

I'm using the current latest jsRender (as of 12/02/2013) and I'm trying to componentise templates so I can render a nested object model.

I want to be able to either;

**1. pass a parameter to my template function so that I can call it recursively with different parameters;**

```
    <script id="tmplQ" myParam="int?" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="rgRow L{:*myParam*} e">  // wrap this in L2/L3/L4 etc depending on myParam
            <div class="td q">{{:q}}</div>
        </div>
        {{for cq templ="#tmlQ(myParam+1)"}}  // increment parameter for recursing
    <script>
```

So basically, I want to pass in myParam with 0 to begin with, and then the template calls itself as it drills down through a nested json object model.

**[Update]** OK, so a searching a few pages farther and it looks like you can do this: [JsRender: How to pass variables into a nested template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325085/jsrender-how-to-pass-variables-into-a-nested-template) but I'd still be keen to see these other options where possible;**[/Update]**

**2. Or failing that, I've been trying to simply include part of a block template in another inline template;**

```
    {{for cq tmpl="#tmplQ"}}         // renders inline template but nothing else
          <div class="rgRow L2 e">         // needed to wrap this in L2
          {{for cq tmpl="#tmplQ"}}     // can't mix inline/block templates
              <div class="rgRow L3 e"> // wanted to wrap this in L3
                  {{for cq tmpl="#tmplQ"/}}  // would work if it got here
              </div>
          {{/for}}
        </div>
    {{/for}}
```

with a simpler library template;

```
<script id="tmplQ" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="td q">{{:q}}</div>
</script>
```

The trouble is, jsRender doesn't seem to support mixing both inline and block styles. As soon as you put `tmpl=` in the `{{for}}` it ignores everything else nested below that. Which is a shame. I'd like to see it support a mixture of the two. It doesn't even throw an error.

**I've also tried to find a syntax like this to simply call a template inline.** Does it exist?

```
    {{for cq tmpl="#tmplQ"}}         // renders inline template but nothing else
          <div class="rgRow L2 e">   // wrap in L2
          {{for cq}}
              {{call tmpl="#tmplQ"}}         // call library template????
              <span>other content</span>
          {{/for}}
        </div>
    {{/for}}
```

but it doesn't work either. I've also tried these to call a template directly.

```
{{tmplQ()}}
{{tmpl("#tmplQ")}}
```

Anyone got a clue, or (Boris) might something make it's way into the next revision please?

Comment: For first part, you can easily do that. The tree tag control example illustrates recursive calls to a tag. You can call for recursively too, and pass different parameters. 
For the second part, yes, there is a feature for associating a template, and having the template then call (wrap) the block content. It will be in the next update, and I will point you to a demo then...

Comment: Thanks Boris. Are you planning to allow templates to contain literal *and* linked templates, or simply a {{tmpl=}} style library call that can be embedded in literal content? The latter approach seems clearer to me.

Comment: Hi cirrus - not sure if I understand exactly your alternative styles. But the best thing would be if you can take a look at the new JsRender feature  mentioned in my answer below (and the linked example using it) and see if it works well with your scenario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest JsRender update, there is now a new ‘wrapped template’ feature for providing both a template  and block content, so that the template can then ‘wrap’ the content.
See http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/06_template-composition.html
for an example.

Comment: Yep, that looks pretty good. I see you can choose where literal content appears, a bit like passing a parameter. So is #content a reserved template name? Can you pass other parameters to include methods?

Comment: #content is the content property of the view object: view.content. #foo is short for view.foo. You notice it is not a string "#content" - so there is no collision with named templates, which are referenced by string name.

Comment: As for passing parameters, you can write {{include ~myparam=expr tmpl=.../}} and then access ~param in the included content, e.g. the wrapped block if you are using tmpl=#content. So you might have {{wrapper}}{{:~myparam}}{{/wrapper}}, where the wrapper tag passed the myparam to its wrapped content as a parameter on {{include .../}}

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I solved the first part of the question using a recursive template. This sets L1, L2, L3 etc based on the parameter passed through;

```
<script id="tmplQ" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="selected stmQ">
        {{for process.qs[0]}}
            {{for cq}}
                <a id="q-{{:stm.n}}">q-{{:stm.n}}</a>
                <div class="table">
                    {{for cq ~depth=1 tmpl="#tmplNestedQ"/}}
                </div>
            {{/for}}
        {{/for}}
    </div>
</script>

<script id="tmplNestedQ" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="rgRow L{{:~depth}} e">
        <div class="td q">{{:q}}</div>
    </div>
    {{for cq ~depth=(~depth+1) tmpl="#tmplNestedQ"/}}
</script>
```